# I can't install anything in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation

I am a new user of Ubuntu, first time in Linux world .

I don't manage to install anything neither from the Ubuntu software center not elsewhere. For example I try to install chrome (I have downloaded the xxx.deb file)...after double clicking I am moved to the installation area ... I click on install and then I get warning message that  "requires the installation of non-trusted packets" (of course in the local language). Then if I click OK I got nothing, if I click the "restore" (the other option) the installation seems to start.  The progress in menu shows 2 steps but later I got he error "failed to retrieve repository information", check the internet connection ... of course the internet is there as I have browsing. When I click on details I got a lot of lines about failures to fetch various things

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: list down the lines of failure please

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem here, it happened that Software Center didn't even open. Looked for many answers and tried many of them, until I looked closer to the error message and I saw there was a problem with a package:

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Translation-pt%5fBR
```

Deleting it fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the sources.list file and open your Graphical Software sources, then enable the various required sources as you desire

[image]

then update your list with this from terminal

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and you can then install software using the

```
 sudo apt-get install <software>
```

**This screen shot is for Lucid Lynx (10.04) but should not look any different**

Comment: The sources are there because when I click on ubuntu software center in the menu "all software" I get all the sources that you refer to ... also I see lists of myriads of applications to download. The apt-get update commands fails ...after waiting some time  trying to connect the connection to the proxy router fails (I use google routing for some reason but I guess this is nt a problem). The apt-get upgrade commands succeeds with the exemption of some packets that cannot be fetched

Comment: Sorry about that but here's a default 12.04 [sources.list](https://gist.github.com/olupotd/9058113/download) file plus i wouldn't use Google proxies for some reasons.